# How many device I can be registered in enterprise developer program

Tags: iphone

I want to distribute my application to my 1000 team members.
Will it be possible through an enterprise developer program?
Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of devices you can distribute to in the Enterprise Program. The 100 Device Limit is only for Individual/Company App Store Programs

Comment: You can read the Enterprise Guide to find out more information: http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can register unlimited number of devices..